# C# connection with SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am writing a desktop application on c# using .NET and will be using a SQL Server database.

How to connect to SQL Server with .net?

When my whole job is completed how will I be able to make a installation package for users such that they don't need to install SQL Server or .net to run the desktop application?

New to c# .... help me out guyz

Comment: Ask your pal Google.

Comment: I think you lack of knowledge on this topic is your downfall.  Perhaps you should start from the beginning.Try a tutorial like this. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in Visual Studio.

- You need to install SQL Server Data Tools in Visual Studio
- View -> SQL Server Object Explorer
- Right-click on SQL Server -> Add SQL Server
- Fill informations about SQL Database and Connect

Comment: thanks kuba for helping me out .... what do u think about my second question?

Comment: When my whole job is completed how will I be able to make a installation package for users such that they don't need to install SQL Server or .net to run the desktop application?

Answer (score 0):

Your C# program will typically have connection information (often stored in a config file) that provides the field values(such as Instance Name, Database Name, User Name and Password) to connect to a remote database. The install program will install all the references (dll's) that allow the calls to SQL Server. You install SQL Server once on a server and run the install program on each client machine if for example you are using Windows Forms.